# Can't change the Target Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sqlclr

I have a project written  in visual studio 2008. I want to upgrade to a newer .NET framework. But everytime I open the project and try to change the target Framework it changes back to .NET 2.0.

Let me know if you need more info.

I open the project in Visual Studio 2013. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to open the project in Visual Studio 2008. Change the target framework to the newest and after that open the project in Visual Studio 2013 and then change the Target Framework to the newest version.